# Javax package does not exist

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

there is an error in all my javax header file "package javax. does not exist" here is an image.

[image]

Comment: There is a missing `jar` file obviously.

Comment: It's not javax that is missing but obex and microedition. Fix you libraries path to include them

Comment: Thanks petar..pls mention the jar file. which i have to include

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the library `Persistence (JPA 2.1)` in your folder `Libraries`.
To do this: Left-click Libraries->Add Library...->select Persistence (JPA 2.1)

Comment: This is valid too for NetBeans 11.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans 6.9.1 already has Java ME SDK 3.0. Just check the Emulator Platform in the properties of your application. If there is no emulator platform just download the [sun java toolkit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html) or [Java ME SDK 3.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/sdk/index.html) and then integrate with Java platform on your netbeans IDE.

Comment: Oh oh! I didnt noticed the IDE. I have updated the new solution.

Answer (score 1):

Download one of the jar file from the following link and store it in your local machine :

http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/javax.obex.Operation

Now follow the given steps in the following link to add that jar file into your project.

http://gpraveenkumar.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/abc-to-import-a-jar-file-in-netbeans-6-5/

This should resolved your errors.

Comment: No need add external `jar` for Java ME application. Just need to add the Java ME platform. I think he missed that.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy, I was facing the same issue and fixed in this way:

1. File -> New File -> Persistence -> New Persistence UNIT

Here you need to select your desire package from drowpdown list and click ok. 
It will add EclipsLink in library folder which has the package javax.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message says: package `javax.obex` does not exist. This means you are missing a library (JAR file). Add the JAR file to your project. In Eclipse you can do that by right-clicking the project, selecting Properties, then Java Build Path, Libraries. Click "Add JARs" or "Add External JARs" to add the relevant JAR file to your project.

This JAR file most likely has something to do with bluetooth. You can download an interface JAR from [here](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr082/), but you most likely need an implementation JAR also.

Comment: Jesper, Look the image clearly. `javax.microedition` also showing error. This error might be a platform configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the project libraries properly setup: it looks like you have added the source jar file to your project, not the jar with actual class files.